# Drupal - Blog post links not working from certain points

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, broken-links

we've put a quick Drupal 6 site as part of a Give-Camp and at the last minute noticed a problem with the site blog's recent posts section.  If you go here: http://closingthenolagap.org/ you can see the problem that I'm talking about under Recent Posts.  Those links *should* exist since those posts do.

We can't figure out what setting we messed up that caused this functionality.  Any help would be appreciated.

See this short screencast for a further demonstration of the problem: http://screencast.com/t/Zjc3MWMwMD

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you might have removed some (all?) of the character replacement rules from the pathauto module (I assume you're using - if not we could do with more info on what modules you do have).

The paths to your blogpost have a lot of URL-encoded characters like %20 (which is a space) - pathauto should be replacing these automatically with dashes or underscores, or removing them.